# pgpool - service don't start: legitimation error

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

If try to start pgpool  I got this error:

```
 administrator@Linux-HA-1:/etc/init.d$ service pgpool2 start

 * Starting pgpool-II
 pgpool
 FD - Starting pgpool-II by executing:

 /usr/sbin/pgpool -n -f /etc/pgpool2/3.5.2/pgpool.conf 
 -F /etc/pgpool2/3.5.2/pcp.conf 



 -a /etc/pgpool2/3.5.2/pool_hba.conf >> /var/log/pgpool/pgpool.log 2>&1 &

 Password:
 su: legitimation error
```

I don't know is it a problem with the pg_md5 to make the rights in the pool_passwd key or in the pcp.conf. The hash is to the same, but user and passwort. :-/

My configuration looks like this. 
[image]

```
select passwd from pg_shadow where usename = 'username';
```

or

```
sudo pg_md5 -f /etc/pgpool2/3.5.2/pgpool.conf -m -u postgres postgrespassword
```

brings the same key for into the 'pool_passwd'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the permision hell! You have to create the pgpool.log file and change the userrights to

```
    -rw-rw-rw
```